# Validate XML against XSD and create log of records that failed

Tags: c#

Have a sample XML

```
<persons>
    <person>
        <fname>John</fname>
        <lname>Doe</lname>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <add_line1>Street</add_line1>
                <zip>1234</zip>
                <state>NY</state>
            </address>
            <address>
                <add_line1>Street</add_line1>
                <zip>1234</zip>
                <state>PA</state>
            </address>
            <address>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </person>
</persons>
```

I can validate it against an XSD and I can get if it passes validation or not

Is it possible to run it through validation wherein I can get the exact record for which validation failed?

Bad XML:

```
<persons>
    <person>
        <fname>John</fname>
        <lname>Doe</lname>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <add_line1>Street</add_line1>
                <zip>1234</zip>
                <state>NY</state>
            </address>
            <address>
                <add_line1>Street</add_line1>
                <zip>1234</zip>
                <state>PAA</state>
            </address>
            <address>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </person>
</persons>
```

The above would fail state validation as state is PAA instead of PA.

So I am looking to get that state validation failed for John Doe and any other user

I can get the records used for creating the xml into a data table - not sure if it is possible to validate the records against XSD - figure the best option is to generate the xml against the xsd and create a log file of all records that failed validation.

Comment: Extract and validate each record...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Could you provide sample guidance or link(s)?